# Is there the way to concate the string for sql select in query()?

Tags: google-sheets

Because the query result is only boolean, string.
When I use the query in sheet, the result is null and it doesn't meet my expectation.

```
=image(url)
```

which is I want to query for.
I try to use

```
=query(data_range,"select '=image('+column" + "')")
```

But the result is the only string, it's not useful.

Then I google it, and try to find the answer in StackOverflow,
someone tells 「&」 logical

and someone tells concat function, but it's still in vain.

I want to ask, is there the way to insert the string concat with the query data,

or another direct way to solve the image sting problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is the logic/correct syntax:

> QUERY(DATA_RANGE, "SELECT Col1 where Col1 CONTAINS '"&IMAGE(URL)&"'")

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I want to query for image data.